# Package installation error: Could not find related list [Histories] for entity [Contact]

Tags: deployment, scratch-org, package, package-install

I'm trying to install a package on a scratch org, but failing at `Could not find related list [Histories] for entity [Contact]`.

My `project-scratch-def.json` looks like the following: And I have also enabled `Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events`. What I'm I missing, any guidance would be highly appreciated!

```json
{
  "orgName": "mbutt company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi", "Communities"],
  "language": "en_US",
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
        "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
        "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "enhancedNotesSettings": {
        "enableEnhancedNotes": true
    },
    "omniChannelSettings": {
        "enableOmniChannel": true
    },
    "liveAgentSettings": {
        "enableLiveAgent": true
    },
    "caseSettings": {
        "emailToCase": {
            "enableEmailToCase": true
        }
    },
    "nameSettings": {
        "enableMiddleName": true,
        "enableNameSuffix": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "chatterSettings": {
        "enableChatter": true
    },
    "languageSettings": {
        "enableTranslationWorkbench": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
        "enableQuote" : true
    },
    "accountSettings": {
        "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
      }
}
}
```

`Histories` is referenced in a `flexipage` in the following way

```
<componentInstanceProperties>
    <name>relatedListApiName</name>
    <value>Histories</value>
</componentInstanceProperties>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing Track Field Level History on the contact object. Check objects/Contact.object-meta.xml and make sure `enableHistory` is `true`.

Comment: Sure did, managed to figure it out at the end. Thank you for taking your time to provide the answer as well!

Comment: Chiming in to this old thread - This popped up for me for a deployment containing one of the new dynamic related lists - the "Related List - Single" component. In my case, it wasn't a History object, but a standard 1:N Lookup relationship. The Dynamic Related List requires the underlying non-Lightning Page Layout to contain a related list to that object. So ensure that (1) the non-Lightning Layout contains a Related List to the other object, (2) the non-Lightning Layout is in your deployment, & (3) that the Lookup field on the other object is included or already present in the destination org.